# A problem of central simple algebras: why $(E,s,\gamma)\cong M_n(F)$ only if $\gamma$ is the norm of an element of $E$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, semi-simple-rings

I am stuck in the following problem, which is the exercise 6 of section 4.6 of N. Jacobson's *Basic Algebra II*:

> **Problem.** Prove that $(E,s,\gamma)\cong M_n(F)$ if and only if $\gamma$ is the norm of an element of $E$.

- Here $F$ is a field, and $E/F$ is a cyclic extension of degree $n$ with $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)=\langle s\rangle$. $(E,s,\gamma)$ is an $n^2$-dimensional central simple algebra over $F$ generated by all matrices $\overline b=\mathrm{diag}\{b, s(b),\cdots,s^{n-1}(b)\}$ ( $\forall b\in E$ ) and 
  $$
  z=\left(\begin{matrix}
  0&1& & &\\
  0&0&1& &\\
  \vdots& &\ddots&\ddots &\\
  0& \cdots&\cdots& 0& 1\\
  \gamma&\cdots&\cdots & 0& 0
  \end{matrix}\right)
  $$
  for a fixed $\gamma\in F^\times$.
- Actually the "if" part is quite obvious as a concrete isomorphism can be formulated (Indeed, the correspondence $\lambda_b\mapsto\overline b$, $\lambda_as\mapsto z$ gives an isomorphism from $\mathrm{End}_FE$ to $(E,s,\gamma)$, where $\gamma=N_{E/F}(a)$ and $\lambda_b$ <s>is the $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}F$-isomorphism  $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{x=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_i\alpha^{i}\mapsto \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_is^{i}(b)\alpha^i}$, in which $\enclose{horizontalstrike}\alpha$ is a primitive element over $\enclose{horizontalstrike}F$).</s>  is the $F$-linear homomorphism $x\mapsto bx$.
- Where I am stuck is the **"only if"** part of this problem. Although the book gives a hint to use Skolem-Noether theorem, I can hardly find where to apply it.  **So I would like to ask how to obtain the implication**

> $(E,s,\gamma)\cong M_n(F)$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\gamma=N_{E/F}(a)$ (i.e., $\gamma=as(a)\cdots s^{n-1}(a)$) for some $a\in E$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Here are some attempts (I will continue to update until a solution is come up):

- I guess this is one probable way. If we denote the isomorphism by $f\colon (E,s,\gamma)\to M_n(F)$<s>, and let $\enclose{horizontalstrike}g$ be the monomorphism from the algebra generated by all $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\overline b}$ to $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{M_n(F)}$ that sends $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\overline b}$ to the matrix of $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\lambda_b}$ under a basis of $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{E/F}$, then the Skolem-Noether theorem tells us that there is a matrix $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{M\in \mathrm{GL}_n(E)}$ such that $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(\cdot)=M^{-1}g(\cdot)M}$. Then  we can define $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{g(z)}$ and it remains to show that $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{g(z)}$ is the matrix of $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{as}$ for some $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{a\in E}$. However, this way seems not working and the use of inner automorphism is still unclear...</s>
- A previous exercise of this section asserts that for each $x\in(E,s,\gamma)$, it can be written in a unique way as
  $$
  x=\overline b_0+\overline b_1 z+\cdots+\overline b_{n-1}z^{n-1}.
  $$
  <s>**If** we can prove that $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{M\in \mathrm{GL}_n(F)}$, then $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{g(z)}$ corresponds a homomorphism $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\zeta\in\mathrm{End}_FE}$. Moreover, since if so, $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{g\colon(E,s,\gamma)\to M_n(F)}$ is an $\enclose{horizontalstrike}F$-linear isomorphism, and thus $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{s\in\mathrm{End}_FE}$ can be written in a unique manner as follows
  $$
  \enclose{horizontalstrike}{s=\lambda_{b_0}+\lambda_{b_1}\zeta+\cdots+\lambda_{b_{n-1}}\zeta^{n-1}}
  $$
  where $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{b_0,\cdots,b_{n-1}\in E}$. Hopefully by $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{s^n=1}$ we **perhaps** can get that all $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{b_i=0}$ but $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{b_1}$ (at least this holds for $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{n=2}$), and then $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\zeta=\lambda_{b_1^{-1}}s}$, which indicates $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\lambda_\gamma=\zeta^n=(\lambda_{b_1^{-1}}s)^n}$, namely $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\gamma=N_{E/F}(b_1^{-1})}$.</s>
- Let us denote by $\iota\colon(E,s,\gamma)\hookrightarrow M_n(E)$ the natural embedding. Then by Skolem-Noether theorem, $\iota(\cdot)=N^{-1}f(\cdot)N$ for some $N\in\mathrm{GL}_n(E)$. Since $f$ is isomorphic, each $x\in M_n(F)$ can be written as
  $$
  x=f(\overline b_0)+f(\overline b_1)f(z)+\cdots+f(\overline b_{n-1})f(z)^{n-1}
  $$
  in a unique manner with $b_i\in E$. Note that $s\in \mathrm{End}_FE$ corresponds to a matrix 
  $$x_s=f(\overline b_0)+\cdots+f(\overline b_{n-1})f(z)^{n-1}\in M_n(F)$$ 
  and $x_s^n=I\in M_n(F)$ (the identity matrix). **If** we can deduce that $f(\overline b_i)=0$ but $f(\overline b_1)$ (again, this holds at least for $n=2$), then it follows that <s>$\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\det(f(\overline b_1z))^n=1}$, and thus $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\det(\overline b_1z)^n=1\Longrightarrow N_{E/F}(b_1)^n\gamma^n=1}$.</s> $x_s=f(b_1)f(z)$ and hence $\gamma I=N_{E/F}(b_1^{-1})I$.
- If it can be shown that $x_sf(\overline b)=f(s(\overline b))x_s$, then that $f(\overline b_i)=0$ but $f(\overline b_1)$ can be deduced, and the arguments before all make sense.

---

**A failed attempt:**

**I tried to prove that the $m_b$ defined as follows corresponds to the matrix $f(\overline b)$ under some $F$-basis of $E$ but at last found that I made several fatal mistakes, having no idea how to fix them for the moment. <s>I think this is very likely to be a working way.</s>**

Assume that $f\colon(E,s,\gamma)\to M_n(F)\subset M_n(E)$. For the inclusion mapping $\iota\colon(E,s,\gamma)\hookrightarrow M_n(E)$, the Skolem-Noether theorem implies that 
$$
f(\cdot)=N^{-1}\iota(\cdot)N
$$
for some $N\in\mathrm{GL}_n(E)$. For a primitive element $\alpha$ of $E/F$, $B:=\{1,\alpha,\cdots,\alpha^{n-1}\}$ is an $F$-basis of $E$. Define for each $b\in E$,
\begin{align}
m_b\colon E&\to E\\
x=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_i\alpha^i&\mapsto\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_is^i(b)\alpha^i
\end{align}
and it follows that $m_b$ is $F$-linear, i.e., $m_b\in\mathrm{End}_FE$. We assert that there is an $F$-basis $B'$ of $E$, under which the matrix of $m_b\ (\forall b\in E)$ is $f(\overline b)$. Indeed, for each $b\in E$,
\begin{align}
m_b(1,\alpha,\cdots,\alpha^{n-1})N=&(b,s(b)\alpha,\cdots,s^{n-1}(b)\alpha^{n-1})N\\
=&(1,\alpha,\cdots,\alpha^{n-1})\overline bN\\
=&(1,\alpha,\cdots,\alpha^{n-1})NN^{-1}\iota(\overline b)N\\
=&(1,\alpha,\cdots,\alpha^{n-1})Nf(\overline b).
\end{align}
Thus it remains to show that $B':=(1,\alpha,\cdots,\alpha^{n-1})N$ is an $F$-basis of $E$. Let us consider the matrix
$$
V=\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&\alpha&\cdots&\alpha^{n-1}\\
1&s(\alpha)&\cdots&s(\alpha^{n-1})\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
1&s^{n-1}(\alpha)&\cdots&s^{n-1}(\alpha^{n-1})
\end{matrix}\right)\in M_n(E).
$$
Since $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)=\langle s\rangle$ and $E=F(\alpha)$, $s^i(\alpha)\neq s^j(\alpha)$ for $i\neq j$ ($i, j=1,\cdots,n$). Therefore the Vandermonde matrix $V\in\mathrm{GL}_n(E)$. If $B'=(1,\alpha,\cdots,\alpha^{n-1})N$ is $F$-linear dependent, <s>then the columns of $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{VN}$ are $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{F}$-(and of course $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{E}$-)linear dependent (since $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{s^i}$ fixes elements of $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{F}$). As $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{N}$ is invertible, it leads to a contradiction that $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{V\notin\mathrm{GL}_n(E)}$. Therefore $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{B'}$ is an $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{F}$-basis of $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{E}$.</s>

Since $M_n(F)\cong \mathrm{End}_FE$, under the basis $B'$, $s$ corresponds to a matrix $x_s\in M_n(F)$. Then
$$
x_s=f(\overline b_0)+f(\overline b_1)f(z)+\cdots+f(\overline b_{n-1})f(z^{n-1})
$$
for some $b_0,\cdots,b_{n-1}\in E$. <s>Note that $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{sm_b=m_{s(b)}s}$ and we have for each $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{b\in E}$, $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{x_sf(\overline b)=f(s(\overline b))x_s}$,</s> while
\begin{align}
x_sf(\overline b)=&f(\overline b_0)f(\overline b)+f(\overline b_1)f(z)f(\overline b)+\cdots+f(\overline b_{n-1})f(z)^{n-1}f(\overline b),\\
f(s(\overline b))x_s=&f(s(\overline b))f(\overline b_0)+f(s(\overline b))f(\overline b_1)f(z)+\cdots+f(s(\overline b))f(\overline b_{n-1})f(z)^{n-1}.
\end{align}

The exercise 4 of section 4.6 of N. Jacobson's *Basic Algebra II* asserts that

> Each $x\in (E,s,\gamma)$ can be written in a unique way as $$x=\overline b_0+\overline b_1z+\cdots+\overline b_{n-1}z^{n-1},$$ where $b_i\in E$.

Thus it follows that

\begin{align}
&f(\overline b_0)f(\overline b)=f(s(\overline b))f(\overline b_0),\\ &f(\overline b_1)f(s(\overline b))=f(s(\overline b))f(\overline b_1),\\
&\quad\vdots\\
&f(b_{n-1})f(s^{n-1}(\overline b))=f(s(\overline b))f(\overline b_{n-1}).
\end{align}

The arbitrariness of $b\in E$ forces that $b_0=b_2=\cdots=b_{n-1}=0$ (precisely speaking,  for each $i=0,2,\cdots,n-1$, pick a $b\in E\setminus F$ which is not fixed by $s^{i-1}$, and then $f(\overline b_i)f(s^i(\overline b))=f(s(\overline b))f(\overline b_i)=f(\overline b_i)f(s(\overline b))$; if $b_i\neq 0$, $f$ being isomorphic entails that $f(s^i(\overline b))=f(s(\overline b))$ and thence, $b=s^{i-1}(b)$, which is a contradiction). Hence $x_s=f(\overline b_1)f(z)$, and the invertibility of $x_s$ implies that $b_1\neq 0$. We thus have

\begin{align}
\gamma I=&f(z)^n=(f(\overline b_1)^{-1}x_s)^n=(f(\overline{b_1^{-1}})x_s)^n\\
=&f(\overline{b_1^{-1}})f(s(\overline{b_1^{-1}}))\cdots f(s^{n-1}(\overline{b_1^{-1}}))x_s^n\\
=&N_{E/F}(b_1^{-1})I,
\end{align}

i.e., $\gamma=N_{E/F}(a)$, where $a=b_1^{-1}\in E^\times$.

Comment: AFAIK, in certain cases (for quaternion algebras, which is the case $n=2$, and for $F$ a local field), one can even show that if $\gamma$ is not a norm from $E$, the cyclic algebra $(E, s, \gamma)$ is a skew field, which would immediately imply your conclusion. Probably that does not hold in this generality, but maybe one could imitate a proof for that to a certain extent.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg If $(E,s,\gamma)$ is a skew field, then I guess it will not be isomorphic to $M_n(F)$ for $n\geqslant 2$? Then how does it imply the conclusion of this problem (Are they contradictory? Since the conclusion of this problem implies that for $n=2$ and $\gamma$ a norm in $E$, there is an isomorphism $(E,s,\gamma)\cong M_n(F)$)?

Comment: Isn't that contraposition? If we had "$\gamma$ is no norm $\implies (E, s, \gamma)$ is a skewfield" then we would have $(E, s, \gamma) \simeq M_n(F) \implies (E, s, \gamma)$ is no skewfield $\implies \gamma$ is a norm".

Comment: About your latest attempt, which looks promising: I am quite sure that $B'$ is a basis, but A) I do not see exactly how exercise 4 implies your "Thus it follows that ..."; and even granted those equations, B) I also do not understand how "the arbitrariness of $b$ forces that $b_0=b_2= ...= b_{n-1}=0$". What is special about $b_1$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Ah, yeah, that's right. I misunderstood your first comment yesterday...But it seems not so easy to prove it for a general $n$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg What I mean is that A) exercise 4 gives the uniqueness of the "decomposition" $x=\overline b_0+\cdots+\overline b_{n-1}z^{n-1}\in (E,s,\gamma)$ and since $(E,s,\gamma)\cong M_n(F)$, each matrix $x=f(\overline b_0)+\cdots+f(\overline b_{n-1})f(z)^{n-1}$ is "decomposed" uniquely in this way, where $f$ is the isomorphism. Then by $x_sf(\overline b)=f(s(\overline b))x_s$ one can establish those equations.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg B) For example, let us just pick a $b\in E\setminus F$ that is not fixed by $s$, and then $f(\overline b_0)f(\overline b)=f(s(\overline b))f(\overline b_0)=f(\overline b_0)f(s(\overline b))$ (note that any $\overline b$ and $\overline{b'}$ commutes). If $b_0\neq 0$, since $f$ is isomorphic, it follows that $f(\overline b)=f(s(\overline b))$ and thus $b=s(b)$, which is a contradiction. Proof for the rest of $b_2,\cdots,b_{n-1}$ is similar, while the equation for $b_1$ gives no contradiction. Now that $x_s$ is invertible, $b_1$ cannot be $0$ (otherwise $x_s=0$).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg For why such a $B'$ is an $F$-basis, currently I have no idea. I think this has something to do with the matrix $N$ in Skolem-Noether theorem, as it is probable that $B'$ is not a basis if we take an arbitrary invertible matrix. E.g., take $n=2$, $F=\mathbb R$, $E=\mathbb C$ and $\alpha=i$. For $B=(1,i)$ and $N=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&0\\ i&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, then $B'=BN=(0,i)$ is not an $F$-basis for $E$.

Comment: I think I get A) and B) now, thank you. The problem with the basis seems to be a confusion due to notational issues to me. The way you identify $End_F(E)$ with $M_n(F)$, (and later one should see $M_n(E) \simeq E \otimes M_n(F)$), your basis just becomes the standard basis consisting of vectors $\pmatrix{1\\0\\.\\0}$, ..., $\pmatrix{0\\.\\0\\1}$, and of course $N$ just changes that to a different basis, namely, the columns (or rows, depending on whether you multiply from the left or right) of $N$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Eh...Surely the columns of $N$ is a basis for $E^n$, but how could we conclude that it transforms a basis of $F^n$ to another basis of $F^n$? Actually, $$(1,\alpha,\cdots,\alpha^{n-1})N=(1,\alpha,\cdots,\alpha^{n-1})M$$ for some $M\in M_n(F)$ and I guess we cannot deduce that $M$ is invertible(?), otherwise how do we explain that in my last comment, $$(1,i)\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\ i&1\end{matrix}\right)=(0,i)=(1,i)\left(\begin{matrix}0&0\\ 0&1\end{matrix}\right)$$ is not an $\mathbb R$-basis for $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Then I don't understand your notation. What I mean is that I would maybe expect you to write $(1,0)$ for $1$, $(0,1)$ for $i$ (identifying $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$), and thus, say, $((1,0),(0,1)) \pmatrix{1&0\\i&1} = ((1,0), (i,1))$ which is a basis (of $\mathbb{C}^2$). -- Independently from that, now I fail to see why $s m_b = m_{s(b)} s$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I am sorry that my notations caused confusion. The reason why I want $B'=(1,\cdots,\alpha^{n-1})N$ to be an $F$-basis of $E$ is that if so, then the matrix of $m_b$ under it is $f(\overline b)$, but as $N$ is a matrix over $E$, $(1,\cdots,\alpha^n)N$ is not actually a basis transformation with transition matrix $N$. Here $B'$ the entries of $n$ are still vectors over $F$, i.e., elements of $E$. I guess in your formulation you lifted their coefficients to $E$ and made them $n$-dimensional vectors over $E$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I agree. Now I also cannot see why $sm_b=m_{s(b)}s$. Then this attempt of proof is nonsense actually. I think I have to look for a new way.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Ah, my problem got an answer before I came up with one of my own. Thank you for your comments and your help~

Comment: Funny, I think I just found how to make your proof work and would have typed that up after Christmas. I might still do it. (It is more or less the accepted proof in disguise, but it is worthwhile to see that disguise. The key is to define $m_b$ as the multiplication with $b$, and then, using some tensor products, to see there actually is a basis (of $E\otimes E \simeq E^n$) w.r.t. which $m_b$ is given by $\bar b$.)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Apologies...I should have hesitated to accept an answer (It's a shame that I always make my decision too quickly). Please do let me know your answer and I will vote for it. Recently I also thought about defining $m_b$ as the left multiplication with $b$ but had not yet worked the proof out. Thank you again, and merry Christmas:)

Comment: Oh no worries, I am not in it for the reputation (at least that's what I tell myself). I will post it when I have time. Merry Christmas to you too.

Comment: Update: When typing up what I thought to be a different proof, I realised there was a gap again which I cannot fill without basically copying the proof in the answer. So for now I've given up on such an alternative proof. Sorry about that.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Anyway I appreciate your help greatly, and thank you for spending time on this little problem~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following argument is copied from the Lemma in Section 15.1 and Lemma in Section 14.2 of [2]. The result is also proven in Corollary 4.7.5 of [1] in a different way.

Let me denote $z_{\gamma}$ for your $z$, and set $\mathcal{A}_{\gamma} := (E,s,\gamma)$ for any $\gamma \in F^{\times}$. Suppose there is an $F$-algebra isomorphism $\varphi : \mathcal{A}_{\gamma} \to \mathcal{A}_{1_{F}}$. The map $b \mapsto \varphi(\overline{b})$ is an $F$-algebra homomorphism $E \to \mathcal{A}_{1_{F}}$, and by Skolem-Noether there exists an $F$-algebra automorphism $\alpha : \mathcal{A}_{1_{F}} \to \mathcal{A}_{1_{F}}$ such that $\alpha(\overline{b}) = \varphi(\overline{b})$ for all $b \in E$. Hence, after replacing $\varphi$ by $\alpha^{-1}\varphi$, we may assume that $\varphi(\overline{b}) = \overline{b}$ for all $b \in E$. Let $\xi : E \to \mathcal{A}_{1_{F}}$ denote the $F$-algebra map $b \mapsto \overline{b}$. Note that $z_{\gamma} \cdot \overline{b} \cdot z_{\gamma}^{-1} = \overline{s(b)}$ for all $\gamma \in F^{\times}$ and $b \in E$. Applying $\varphi$, we get $\varphi(z_{\gamma}) \cdot \overline{b} \cdot \varphi(z_{\gamma})^{-1} = \overline{s(b)}$, which implies $(z_{1_{F}}^{-1}\varphi(z_{\gamma})) \cdot \overline{b} \cdot (z_{1_{F}}^{-1}\varphi(z_{\gamma}))^{-1} = \overline{b}$ for all $b \in E$; in other words $z_{1_{F}}^{-1}\varphi(z_{\gamma}) \in C_{\mathcal{A}_{1_{F}}}(\operatorname{im} \xi)$. One may check $C_{\mathcal{A}_{1_{F}}}(\operatorname{im} \xi) = \operatorname{im} \xi$ (using the fact that each $a \in \mathcal{A}_{1_{F}}$ can be written in a unique way as $a = \overline{b_{0}} + \overline{b_{1}}z_{1_{F}} + \dotsb + \overline{b_{n-1}}z_{1_{F}}^{n-1}$ with $b_{i} \in E$). Thus $\varphi(z_{\gamma}) = z_{1_{F}}\overline{x}$ for some $x \in E^{\times}$. Taking $n$th powers gives $\overline{\gamma} = \overline{x} \dotsb \overline{s^{n-1}(x)}$ since $(\varphi(z_{\gamma}))^{n} = \varphi(z_{\gamma}^{n}) = \varphi(\overline{\gamma}) = \overline{\gamma}$.

References:

[1] P. Gille and T. Szamuely, "Central Simple Algebras and Galois Cohomology", Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, Vol. 101 (2006)

[2] R. S. Pierce, "Associative Algebras", Graduate Texts in Mathematics, Vol. 88, Springer-Verlag (1982)

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I have been entangled in this problem for a fortnight. Your proof is nice and clear and I guess I have already understood it~